# How to remove "[]" from within a list?

Tags: python, list

Where I have empty elements within lists, [] appears? I'm not sure how to remove this? My list that I'm appending to is copying text from another file. It ends up looking like so:

```
print(List)

['3111111', '09980709', '23332323', []]
```

Comment: `[x for x in List if x]` - btw, you should try to avoid using python reserved keywords (`List`) for variables names

Comment: `List` is neither reserved nor a keyword. Neither is `list`, though it is defined in the built-in scope.

Comment: what if you wanted to have blank entries and not actually remove them all together

Comment: @Sam `['' if x == [] else x for x in List]`

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't produce that in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
x = [2,[], 3, [], 4]
x = [i for i in x if i != []]
print(x)
```

And the result is :

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What if i wanted to leave them as blank entries??

Comment: So they exist, but just dont resemble any values

Comment: You may replace them with 'None'.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the built-in function `filter`:

```
my_list = ['3111111', '09980709', '23332323', []]
my_list = list(filter(None, my_list))
my_list
```

output:

```
['3111111', '09980709', '23332323']
```

note that my approach will not work if in your list will contain empty strings

Comment: My answer was very close to yours `[*filter(bool, x)]`

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways.

**List comprehension**

`[_ for _ in List if _]`

**Lambda filtering**

`[*filter(lambda _: _!=[], List)]`

**List method**

`List.remove([])  # note that this occurs inplace`

To *replace* an element in the list, list comprehension works well.

`[_ if _!=[] else '' for _ in List]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `np.array`:

```
lst = ['3111111', '09980709', '23332323', []]
s = np.array(lst)
lst = list(s[np.where(s)])
```